# How to Interpret/Calculate HVAC Load Impact from Rerigerators

Tags: hvac, refrigerator

I am comparing options to purchase a single walk-in cooler, or several reach-in refrigerators to achieve similar storage capacity to the walk-in.

In addition to capital/maintenance cost, redundancy, and space requirements, I am interested in other variables, such as the impact each refrigeration choice has on the HVAC load for the room.

- The walk-in has a remote refrigeration system (i.e., heat from the cooler is transferred outdoors).
- The reach-in refrigerators are self-contained and heat is transferred to the same room as the refrigerators.

The manufacturer's spec sheet for a 39 cubic foot, self-contained refrigerator reads:
`BTU/H H.P.: 2220 (1/3)`. Other electrical data includes `115/60/1 10.6 full amperes`.

**Is the correct interpretion:** "The 1/3 Horse Power unit emits 2,220 BTU heat per hour; therefore, the HVAC must handle an additional 2,220 BTU per hour"?

That feels high intuitively, but my only reference point is a gas stove burner at 15,000 BTU.

If that interpretation is **in**correct, how may I (or can I even) use this information to determine total heat introduced to the room from the self contained refrigeration?

*(Note: my intention is only to understand the differences between scenarios so as to form a comprehensive comparison of options. Rough guidelines for interpretation are sufficient.*

*EDIT: I also understand that holding temperature, and drawing product temerature down, frequency of door opening, etc. play a role in the impact. I need to find a realistic approximation. If assumptions are needed to form a baseline, assume a holding state at 35 F, where products are at temperature and doors remain shut."*

Comment: The specs typically indicate maximum power and/or constant-state running power (i.e., excluding momentary start-up surge requirement). But refrigerators (of any size) don't run continuously. The **duty cycle** is key to figuring this out. But anecdotally, if you are in a primary air conditioning mode (and even if you are in a heating mode, the kitchen is probably where you *don't* want extra heat even in the winter), the walk-in that sends the heat outdoors will do a lot better in overall efficiency when HVAC is included in the calculation.

Comment: You also can't assume the same duty cycle (20% or whatever) for different types of refrigerators. They may have compressors/etc. sized differently based on concerns beyond pure size - the one with the larger (after consideration of space and insulation) compressor will run at a lower duty cycle (roughly offsetting the size) and be able to handle changes (moved in a day's worth of production all at once) better. No simple answer.

Comment: That beats me to, and  invalidates my follow up question re: ballpark estimates for duty cycles. However, if the duty cycle is known for a specific unit (say 35%), is the iterpretation in my question correct once a duty cycle is applied? (2,220 * 35% = 777 btu/h).

Comment: Correct. Problem is figuring out the duty cycle. The duty cycle isn't "for a unit". It is "for a unit + usage pattern (how often is the door opened and for how long is it open, what temperature is food when it is put into the refrigerator) + external temperature".

Comment: The duty cycle varies. What it is while holding already cold food overnight (presuming "closed business" at that point) with the doors closed is going to be quite different from having food needing to be cooled down added and the doors being opened frequently while cooking is actively going on in the daytime/evening or whenever the business is open. And even for cold food, overnight, doors shut, different units have different amounts of insulation (usually walk-ins have much more insulation than reach-ins. Two reach-ins may have different amounts of insulation.)

Comment: Qualitatively, a commercial reach in cooler helps to make that part of the kitchen unpleasantly hot...

Comment: @Ecnerwal - agreed. I'm trying to quantify (with as many assumtions/caveats attached as needed to validate the figure) to illustrate that to someone that won't understand that note remoting large amounts of refrigeration has implications indoors.

Comment: While it's unusual (because they are the expensive parts, and price does not scale with size much, so one bigger one costs much less than 2 at half the  capacity, or 1/3 & 2/3 the capacity)  if **redundancy** is an important goal, using one walk-in cooler with 2 totally separate cooling units would be an option.

Comment: You really can think of the cooling capacity of a fridge as an even larger heat source (ok it has been a while since I had an HVAC class but I don’t think they have developed perpetual motion yet) or to say it another way the fridge is just moving energy from one location to another and that takes energy , it is true the actual compressor duty cycle may be low but the heat being exchanged thanks longer. I would take the average btu + a small amount for inefficiency and use that for a comparison to the walk in that usually have superior insulation and no heating of the kitchen. Compressor cool+

Comment: Have you considered contacting the manufacturer to confirm your suspicions about what their product labeling means? After all, you're asking us to confirm your guess and without a mfgr name or product link, all we can do is guess, too. A quick call or an on-line chat with their support folk should get you an answer in less time than it took you to write up this question (especially since it's a well written question).

Comment: @FreeMan -- great idea and that's my usual MO.  This grew from a quick [simple?] add-on for a larger analysis, to a complicated question.  Plus, its trade show week for the rep I would call. I didn't want to pester them if I already had the answer on the spec sheet (especially given the analysis is clearly showing their product is the wrong solution for this project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reach-in refrigerator will add all the heat it's removing from the cooled space, PLUS all the waste heat generated by the motor and compressor that's not contributing to moving heat from the cooled space.

With a remote compressor and condenser, both the heat removed and the heat from the motor and compressor are outside.

Given a raw power input claimed at 115V * 10.6A = 1.219KW, that alone is 4159 BTU/hr. That may be more of a peak than running number, though.

It's unclear what, exactly, the 2220 BTU/Hr is referring to. It might be the amount of heat moved from the refrigerator by the 1/3 HP motor, indicating a COP (Coefficient of performance) of 2.6 or so (taking 1/3 HP as 246 Watts, ignoring electrical to mechanical inefficiencies, which may be rather large given the raw power input above.) For room cooling load, there would be an additional 846 BTU/hr contributed by the motor and an unknown but non-trivial additional amount contributed by the actual electrical input (considerably larger than 246 Watts) to run the motor, dissipated as waste heat into the room.

You can get a better idea if you know what the typical running power consumption of the refrigerator is. But more than 3066 BTU/Hr (heat from refrigerator + heat to run motor/compressor) when running, since there **will** be inefficiency in converting electricity to mechanical power.

When you'll care about heat in the space is while people are there working, and that will be when the refrigerator is working hard with doors opening and warm or hot food being added to get cooled down. But the duty cycle is hard to know, or even guess at.

Comment: This, and the other comments helped me formulate a discription of the implications, even if I couldn't provide a number. It's also inspired me to to dig deeper into the math when I get some time. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

The reach-in refrigerators will add **exactly their operating wattage to the room**, and no more.

*Wait. What about all the heat they're removing from the interior of the refrigerator?  Aren't they adding that to the room also?*

Nope. Because that heat **came from the room in the first place** - that is, it made the room cooler by leaking through the insulation, and is being pumped back where it came from.

Obviously if you ran the refrigerator with the door wide open, the heat pumping would cancel itself out and the only thermal load would be the electric consumption. Well, it is the same with the door closed.

So, you can simply plug in a Kill-a-Watt and measure *average* wattage of the fridge - typically 40-50 - and multiply that by 3.41 for BTUs/hour.

Note that since the walk-in fridge is dumping heat outside, it is actually a *net heat drain* from the room.  When you open the door and let a bunch of heat into the fridge, the furnace will have to run longer to replace that heat. Effectively the wall of the walk-in fridge is an outside wall.

I don't know about efficiency, that depends tremendously on quality of wall insulation. However, when a refrigeration unit must work with a wide range of exchange (outdoor/outside-the-fridge) temperatures, compromises must be made which hurt efficiency. Whereas a residential refrigerator can count on 50-100F "outside" temperature.

Lastly, what occurs to me is reliability. Big complex built-in systems take a lot of engineering, custom freon work, and create *a single point of failure* with a long delay to repair due to need for specialists.  Whereas, if one of four refrigerators goes kaput, you can salvage almost all of the food by cramming it into the remaining refrigerators, and have a replacement in the driving time to Home Depot + 30 minutes.  There's a case to be made for K.I.S.S. C.O.T.S.

Comment: Great thoughts.  Thanks. "...Because that heat came from the room in the first place..." I had thought about this, almost to the point of excluding teh comparison.  Your next comment "...walk-in ... a net heat drain from the room..." aligns with why I kept this consideraton. It's heat that needs to be addressed that otherwise wouldn't be.